Vector in a Struct - passing the Struct by its Pointer does not pass the contents of the Vector
In a C++ .exe, I have a struct defined and instantiated:
struct closeVars
{
    HANDLE                              hNeedDataEvent;
    UINT32                              ui32FramesInBuffer;
    UINT32                              ui32BytesToSkip;
    UINT32                              ui32BytesThisPass;
    UINT32                              ui32BuffersPlayed;
    UINT32                              ui32BuffersInFile;
    UINT32                              nFramesThisPass;
    IAudioRenderClient*                 objIAudioRenderClient;
    BYTE*                               pByteDACBuffer;
    std::vector<BYTE*>                  vecpByteMusicData;
};

struct closeVars closeData;
... 
    

Variables of the struct are populated and specifically, vector vecpByteMusicData in the struct is populated with 986 elements.
I pass a pointer to this struct to a function in an external DLL like so:
render(&closeData);
    

In the external DLL, this is the code:
struct x_closeVars
{
    HANDLE                              hNeedDataEvent;
    UINT32                              ui32FramesInBuffer;
    UINT32                              ui32BytesToSkip;
    UINT32                              ui32BytesThisPass;
    UINT32                              ui32BuffersPlayed;
    UINT32                              ui32BuffersInFile;
    UINT32                              nFramesThisPass;
    IAudioRenderClient*                 objIAudioRenderClient;
    BYTE*                               pByteDACBuffer;
    std::vector<BYTE*>                  vecpByteMusicData;
};
    
extern "C"
{
    extern __declspec(dllexport) VOID render(void* x_ptrCloseData)
    {
        x_closeVars* x_closeData = static_cast<closeVars*>(x_ptrCloseData);
        ...
        // At this point the variables in struct x_closeData contain valid data EXCEPT for the vector in the struct - it shows its size as 491 and each element is NULL.
    }
}

I have also tried passing just the vector by value, but it's the same case with that too - size is 491 and each element is NULL.
Any hints to what I might be doing wrong?

Check the size and alignment of the struct on both sides of the DLL boundary. But even if they match, this code is still dangerous. There is no guarantee that EXE and DLL are using the same implementation of the std::vector class. You can't share non-POD data across a DLL boundary unless you can ensure several requirements are met, like using the same compiler, the same configuration, the same runtime, the same standard library, etc. And even that's still iffy. For sharing purposes, you should change the vecpByteMusicData member to be a raw BYTE** pointer instead.

@AviBerger, yes, same compiler, compiler version and same settings.

Running a debug build of the EXE and a release build of the DLL, by any chance? These would also differ in the definition of std::vector. As a sanity check, print sizeof(std::vector<BYTE*>) on both sides. (The two numbers being the same doesn't by itself guarantee that the two implementations are compatible; but if they are different, it's the sure sign the implementations are incompatible.) But in any case, you are walking on eggshells. It's best to define the DLL's interface in a way that doesn't require sharing non-POD types. E.g. have it take BYTE**, pass myvector.data()

Unrelated, but why are you redefining the structure? Why isn't it defined in a public header file distributed with the library and that you can include? For two structures to be the "same", they need to be an exact character-by-character copy of each other. If they aren't then they are considered different structures and using them will lead to undefined behavior.

@ThraxAn "yes, same compiler, compiler version and same settings" -- And to be honest, the chances of that actually being the case are slim.  Just one "odd" setting that you may miss will make things different, given that there are so many settings all over the place that can make a difference.

@IgorTandetnik, you were right! The sizeof of the vector on both sides of the boundary were 24 and 32. On checking, I found that the EXE was linked with the "Multi-threaded" (/MT) runtime lib and the DLL with the "Multi-threaded Debug DLL" (/MDd) runtime lib.
I set the EXE to link with the "Multi-threaded Debug" (/MTd) runtime lib and now get sizeof of the vector on both sides of the boundary as 32. Data is populated just fine in the vector and all's well now.
Many thanks!!!!!
